# What type of stream does AVMediaType AVMEDIA_TYPE_NB represent

Tags: ffmpeg

The FFmpeg AVMediaType enum contains AVMEDIA_TYPE_NB.
What type of data stream does this contain?
The name isn't very descriptive and the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__misc.html#ga9a84bba4713dfced21a1a56163be1f48) doesn't describe it either.

Search results seem to indicate that it's used as a catch all value to remove packets. with a codec_type of AVMEDIA_TYPE_NB ever exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constants in enums that end with _NB are used as the terminal member. They don't represent any entity. They are used as a loop terminator. NB = number

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I understand the use now.